# Add / remove div for each button on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm trying use `append` to give each button it's own div (`.modal-item`) that can be created and removed inside of the `.modal` container when the button is clicked. Each `.item` has it's own button and different content nested inside.

**What I need as an example:** If I click the button labelled `Btn 1`, I want a `.modal-item` div created inside of `.modal` that has the content from the `Btn 1` `.item`. If I click `Btn 1` again, it is removed. The same goes for each of the buttons.

The buttons should act as a `checkbox` for creating and removing the `.modal-items`. So in other words, the adding/removing of each `.modal-item` is handled by it's button.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    var newDiv = $('<div class="modal-item"><h4><a>Dynamic Title</a></h4> </div>');
    $('.modal').append(newDiv);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item,
.modal-item {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.modal {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <button id="btn">Btn 1</button>
    <h4> Test 1 </h4>
    <div class="subtitle"> Title 1 </div>
    <div class="info"> This is Info / Description 1. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <button id="btn">Btn 2</button>
    <h4> Test 2 </h4>
    <div class="subtitle"> Title 2 </div>
    <div class="info"> This is Info / Description 2. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <button id="btn">Btn 3</button>
    <h4> Test 3 </h4>
    <div class="subtitle"> Title 3 </div>
    <div class="info"> This is Info / Description 3. </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal"></div>
```

Comment: You cannot repeat ids, such as `btn`.  Use a class instead.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page

Comment: You give a lot of requirements, but I don't actually notice a question. What is your question? What part do you need help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st: id must be unique** so you need to change `id="btn"` to `class="btn"`

**2nd:** by using `data` attribute for each btn and pass it to the modal-item div it can be done

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    var newDiv = $('<div data-btn="'+$(this).attr("data-btn")+'" class="modal-item"><h4><a>Dynamic Title'+ ($(this).closest('.item').index() + 1) +'</a></h4> </div>');
    if($('.modal .modal-item[data-btn="'+$(this).attr("data-btn")+'"]').length < 1 ){
      $('.modal').append(newDiv);
    }else{
      $('.modal .modal-item[data-btn="'+$(this).attr("data-btn")+'"]').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item,
.modal-item {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.modal {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <button class="btn" data-btn="btn1">Btn 1</button>
    <h4> Test 1 </h4>
    <div class="subtitle"> Title 1 </div>
    <div class="info"> This is Info / Description 1. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <button class="btn" data-btn="btn2">Btn 2</button>
    <h4> Test 2 </h4>
    <div class="subtitle"> Title 2 </div>
    <div class="info"> This is Info / Description 2. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <button class="btn" data-btn="btn3">Btn 3</button>
    <h4> Test 3 </h4>
    <div class="subtitle"> Title 3 </div>
    <div class="info"> This is Info / Description 3. </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal"></div>
```